# Wavelet Analysis: A notation problem in this paper

Tags: wavelets

Because of my research work, I am reading this paper: [PDE net](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.09668.pdf). But I ran into a notation problem: In definition 2.1, I do not understand how $\textbf{q}[ \textbf{k} ]$ yields a real number. Therefore, I could not verify the authors' claims about the order of sum rules of the Haar wavelet frame filter bank and also the filter
\begin{equation*}
\textbf{q} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
2 & 0 & -2 \\
1 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
I checked their citations and some other literatures, but most of them just said $\{\textbf{q}[\textbf{k}]\}$ is a sequence of real numbers, which does not help me to understand the order of sum rules at all. I am grateful if anyone could give me some hint about this notation.

Comment: Since $k \in \mathbb{Z}^2$, the obvious guess is to take $k$ as a pair of indices into the matrix, and 0 if it's outside the bounds of the matrix. Does not that work?

Comment: It works! I can't believe the authors put it in this way! I have been guessing it is about convolution at $\textbf{k}$. Thank you so much.